# Looping code through database records

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database with some records in and i have the code i wish to execute on each row but I'm having trouble creating a suitable loop, ive been trying while(movetonext) but it hasnt been working.

```
cursor = getAppts();

cursor.moveToNext();

String titlefromdb = cursor.getString(3);

if (strTitle.equals(titlefromdb) && cursor.getString(1).equals(dateselforap))
{
    // matching code update box

    final Dialog matchdiag = new Dialog(CW2Organisor.this);
    matchdiag.setContentView(R.layout.apptmatch);
    matchdiag.setTitle("View/Edit Appointment");
    matchdiag.setCancelable(true);

    TextView  matchtxt = (TextView) matchdiag.findViewById(R.id.matchtxt);

    matchtxt.setText("Appointment \"" + titlefromdb + "\" already exists, please choose a different event title");

    Button btnmatchok = (Button) matchdiag.findViewById(R.id.btnmatch);
    btnmatchok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // on click for cancel button

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            matchdiag.dismiss();
        }
    });

    matchdiag.show();
}
else
{
addAppt(strTime, strTitle, strDet);
dialog.dismiss();
}
```

What I would need is for each row of my database i would need the titlefromdb to hold the title field of the current row and the for the if statement to run and then move to the next row.

Comment: please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
 cursor.moveToFirst();

 loop with some sort of check
    cursor.moveToNext();
 end loop
```

... and I would also try to qualify your "it's not working" statement.  What's not working?

Comment: I was getting an outofbounds exception from my database i beleive.